# how to solve the error 'gswin32c.exe' not found?

Tags: r, plot

I want submit figures to a journal which requires a high quality figures `min dpi is 300` so I tried to save my plot with high quality but I am getting an error.

my plot contains several figures.
Example:

```
  par(mfrow=c(2,4))
 x=c(5,2,4,5,8,7)
 x1=c(5,2,4,5,8,7)
 x2=c(5,2,4,5,8,7)
 x3=c(5,2,4,5,8,7)
 plot(x)
 plot(x1)
 plot(x2)
 bitmap("Plot118.tiff", height = 531, width = 1328, type="tifflzw", res=300)

    Error in system(paste(gsexe, "-help"), intern = TRUE, invisible = TRUE) : 
    'gswin32c.exe' not found
```

Any help please on how to solve this problem or to produce a high quality figure?

Comment: Do you need `tiff`'s? Journals have never rejected my high res `png` files.

Comment: Use the `png` function, or if you are using `ggplot2` `ggsave.

Comment: i used this`png(filename = "Rplot%03d.png",
+     width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", pointsize = 12)` but the output file was empty.any hint

Comment: What are you plotting? Bitmap formats only make sense for maps, contour plots and stuff like that. Most graphs I'd submit to a journal should be vector graphics. Usually you'd send a PDF.

Comment: How to save the figure as `pdf`with this:`height = 531, width = 1328, dpi=300)`

Comment: The term dpi is not applicable to vector files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to run the `bitmap` command, you need Ghostscript installed. Once that is installed, you probably also need to set the `GS_CMD` environment variable. See also [this question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-point-R-toward-Ghostscript-on-a-Windows-XP-system-td3218350.html) on the R-devel mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way: install [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/), create your plot, and use the Export -> Save as PDF option. There you can specify the pdf size.

Comment: If you save as PDF you get a vector graphic as output that can be scaled to any size. So the `dpi` do not matter for such a file type.